# Add "Bijlage" or "Appendices" as prefix before "A" at the top of the page

Tags: appendix

Working on a short report without a toc. The report has some appendices and I'm trying to name them the proper way APA style.

What would like to see at top of he page:

**Bijlage A. Formulier Onderzoeksthema en Vraagstelling**

The current result:

**A. Formulier Onderzoeksthema en Vraagstelling**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,oneside,fontsize=10pt,
  parskip=full]{scrartcl}


\input{preamble}

\begin{document}


\input{0.tex}

\input{1.tex}


\printbibliography

\newpage
\appendix
\section{Formulier Onderzoeksthema en Vraagstelling}
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.8]{b1.pdf}


\end{document}
```

**Preamble**

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfsubject = {Recruitment},
    pdftitle = {Het gebruik van artificiële intelligentie
                        bij werving-en-selectie},
    pdfauthor = {Peter},
    hidelinks,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

% packages for tiltepage
\usepackage{background}
% to remove the default content 'Draft' (default setting in background package)
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfsubject = {Recruitment},
    pdftitle = {Het gebruik van artificiële intelligentie
                        bij werving-en-selectie},
    pdfauthor = {Peter Vissers},
    hidelinks,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    }

% Used to include pdf files
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatuurlijst.bib}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are currently not sharing the contents of your file `preamble` with us, so we don't know which packages you are using. F.i. are you loading `babel` with the language support for Dutch? (`\usepackage[dutch]{babel}`) This takes care not only of language-specific conventions and of hyphenation at line breaks and other, but it also translates many of the LaTeX-generated English terms (such as "Chapter", "Appendix", "References"). So while not the whole answer to your query, that might be relevant to you.

Comment: Thank you marquinho, I have added the preamble I'm using. Still it only shows up as A. Formulier Onderzoeksthema en Vraagstelling

Comment: Or maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499226/annex-to-letter-in-appendix-table-of-contents is a bit more focused.

Comment: Thank you Marijn,  the answer provided in your second suggestion does work.